# How to check which radio button is checked

Tags: php, html

I want a script in PHP that can check which radio button is checked.  I have 2 radio buttons (e.g. `rad1` and `rad2`).  When the user clicks on one button and submit, I want to echo that value from that radio button.

I have found an example, but it is very bad: [example](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_complete.asp)

I have created this for email and pass:

```
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password= $_POST['password'];

if (isset($email)  && !empty($email) ) {
    echo $email;

    if (isset($password) && !empty($password)) {
        echo $password;
    }
}
```

The form:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="student">Student<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="profesor">Profesor<br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I check for which radio button has been checked?

Comment: Can you share the HTML code of your form too?

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email"><br/>

    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"><br/>

    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="student">Student<br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="profesor">Profesor<br>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php

$sex = isset($_POST['sex']) ? trim($_POST['sex']) : null;
switch($sex) {
    case 'student' :

        break;

    case 'profesor' :

        break;

    default :

        break;
}
```

Comment: but I don't understand why student and professor is in $sex ? don't You doing XXX portal? (:

Comment: no.. it was female and male.. and i just leave it then.. not sex like sex.. it is sex like female and male..

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="radio" name="rad1" value="1">
<input type="radio" name="rad2" value="1">
<button type="submit">SEND</button>
</form>

<?php

$rad1 = isset($_POST['rad1'])?trim($_POST['rad1']):null;
$rad2 = isset($_POST['rad2'])?trim($_POST['rad2']):null;
switch($rad1) {
    case 1 :
        // do something
      break;

    default: 
       // do something if null
      break;
}
```

Comment: An `<input type="rad1">` doesn't make much sense - I'm guessing you where going for `<input type="radio" name="rad1">`?

Comment: That looks better. It might also be a bit excessive to allow any value to be set in $rad1 (only trimming), and then use a switch to allow a specific value _1_ or _anything else_. Perhaps setting `$rad1 = isset($_POST['rad1'])? 1 : 0;` would be more explicit.

Comment: my code gives opportunity to make multiple radios with same name, to give multiple values or something else to make it available to pass to switch(){}

Comment: but i must agree if You want only to know if it's checked or not so we can do $rad1 = isset($_POST['rad1'])? true : false; and then pass it to if(){} construction

Comment: In that case, I find the example a bit confusing since you add two radio buttons rad1/rad2, both with value 1 - but only add a switch statement for rad1.